# How to get nearby locations from latitude/longitude?

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have store various latitude and longitude in database(Sqlite3) for various location. Now I have current latitude and longitude. How can I know nearest locations from current position.
Please suggest.

Comment: What constitutes a "location", exactly? A lat/lng pair? A street address? A nearby store name? I mean, one very near location to a lat/lng pair can be gotten by adding .00000000001 to the latitude.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about Reverse Geocoding. There's an Apple class provided for that, [MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html). There are also plenty of how-to discussions about that, such as [here](http://evilrockhopper.com/2010/01/iphone-development-reverse-geocoding/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122144/iphone-reverse-geocoding-give-all-possible-streets-suburbs), etc.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax will likely need to change, but take a look at [this question that uses MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626886/find-nearest-places-by-latitude-and-longitude). Essentially you want to create a rectangle with the current point at the center (most likely). Using the bounds of this new box, you can run your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I dare say @Kongress answer is the best here - but I'm just going to chuck this one into the ring as the concept itself is one that I've dealt with before.

I can't tell you how to build one in objective-c, but for our lat/long reverse lookup I built a [K-DTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) from the lat longs in our database ( > 250,000) and it gives us sub-100-nanosecond lookups on desktop hardware.  On an iphone it's still likely to be pretty fast - memory might be a concern though as you really need to be able to cache the instance in memory, to be really useful; it takes a little while to build it (ours builds in about 1.5 seconds).

Just an idea.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I have find the solution as following query but ACOS function is not working in sqlite3.Select Lat, Lon, acos(sin($lat)*sin(radians(Lat)) + cos($lat)*cos(radians(Lat))cos(radians(Lon)-$lon))$R As dist From MyTable ORDER BY dist DESC